# Nonsmoking or Non-smoking

Tags: orthography, hyphenation, compounds

Would one *write* that someone is “a ***nonsmoking*** so-and-so” or “a ***non-smoking*** so-and-so”? I'm not sure if the hyphen is necessary or superfluous.

Comment: It is optional, like all silent punctuation marks. If you can't hear it, you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

Style guides differ on this issue of punctuation. *The Chicago Manual of Style*, fifteenth edition (2003) recommends closing up practically all prefixed words including those beginning with *non-*:

> **Hyphenation Guide for Compounds, Combining Forms, and Prefixes**
>
> ...
>
> **3. Words Formed with Prefixes**
>
> Compounds formed with prefixes are normally closed, whether they are nouns, verbs, adjectives, or adverbs.
>
> ...
>
> [Relevant examples:] **non:** nonviolent, nonevent, nonnegotiable, *but* non-beer-drinking

*The Associated Press Stylebook* (2002) doesn't endorse closing up words that begin with *non-* as categorically as *Chicago* does. Nevertheless, *nonsmoking* appears to fall into its approved group of closed-up spellings:

> **non-** The rules of **prefixes** apply, but in general no hyphen when forming a compound that does not have special meaning and can be understood if *not* is used before the base word. Use a hyphen, however, before proper nouns or in awkward combinations, such as *non-nuclear*.

*Words Into Type*, third edition (1974) concurs with *Chicago* and *AP*:

> **Prefixes.** The modern tendency is to eliminate the hyphen between a prefix and a root unless the root is a proper noun or adjective, such as un-American [cross reference omitted]. ...
>
> [Relevant examples:] nonnative, nonviolent

The guide least inclined to endorse closing up (most) prefixes is *The Oxford Style Guide* (2006):

> **5.10.2 Prefixes and combining forms**
>
> Words with prefixes are often set as one word, but use a hyphen to avoid confusion or mispronunciation, particularly where there is a collision of vowels or consonants:
>
> [Relevant examples:] non-effective, non-negotiable
>
> The hyphen is used less in US practice. Words beginning with *non-* and *re-*, for example, are often set as one word:
>
> [Relevant examples:] noneffective, nonnegotiable

Notice, however, that *nonsmoking* isn't a spelling that invites confusion or mispronunciation, nor does it involve a collision of consonants in the way that *non-negotiable* (for example) does. So its entirely possible that Oxford would either approve or tolerate closing up *nonsmoking*—and the three U.S. style guides unanimously endorse it.

Because hyphenation is ultimately a style issue, you can hyphenate or close up as you prefer, unless you are writing for a publication that specifies a preferred style that you must follow. But in the United States, at least, the strong preference appears to be for *nonsmoking*, closed up.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that both are acceptable.

However, when referring to a person, I would say that "he/she is not a smoker," or "he/she does not smoke," as opposed to referring to him/her as a non-smoking individual.

I would use non-smoking to refer to areas or airplanes/flights.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely a personal preference, I prefer not to join the word in the absence of a hyphen but to rather have two words i.e. non smoking or non-smoking not nonsmoking.

Comment: Agree. "Nonsmoking" is not a word. Hyphenate or seperate the words.

Comment: @MoniqueH  M-W disagrees http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/nonsmoking